# Anaconda M1 Mac Install Issues

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

I installed Python through **Anaconda's 64-bit Graphical Installer Python 3.8** but when I checked the version it shows 2.7, any advice?

The below commands also does not work when I try to uninstall/remove anaconda:

```
rm -rf ~/anaconda3
conda install anaconda-clean ーー> (Error msg :　zsh: command not found: conda）
anaconda-clean
anaconda-clean --yes
```

I tried using the command line installer and it doesn't work either.

Is there any way to safely remove Anaconda and the Anaconda Navigator?

Answer (score 0):

Try typing `python3` instead of just `python`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're shell (bash / zsh) is initializing anaconda.

If you're using zsh, run `cat ~/.zshrc` and check for a script that looks like this:

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/<username>/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/<username>/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/<username>/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Users/<username>/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

If you're using bash, run `cat ~/.bash_profile`, but the script should be the same.

If it's not there, you may have missed something during installation. I would recommend just downloading the shell script (cli) installer and running again.

Ultimately, if that conda initialization script has executed successfully, you should see (base) before in your terminal.